# User Interface to analaze date of a conventional rdbms

Tags: database, jakarta-ee, jasper-reports, birt, jasperserver

Currently we create Jasper PDF Reports from a single simple database table for our customers. This has been achieved programmatically. It's static. If the user wishes to change the query, he/she creates a change request, which we cannot deliver before the end of the next sprint (SCRUM).

The tool/library should be straight forward (e.g. convention over configuration) and employable from within a JavaEE container. And, open source.

Is there a dynamic tool that allows or customers to create the simple queries/reports themselves without knowing SQL? Means, they should be able to see the table and then create a query from it, execute and print (we could use Jasper Reports for the last one).

E.g. Select only data from year 2014, aggregate them by customer group and select columns x,y and z.

All of these criterias and query structure may change though, thus not just the value like year 2014.

Questions: 
1) Is there a tool that presents the data in some kind of SAP-cube or something similar where the user could select the structure and attributes?
2) Can that tool save template queries (queries that the user has invoked before)?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

With BIRT you could use parameters in the report... for example have one report that shows the whole data set or data cube (or at least a bit of all of the fields). Then you could add JavaScript to the report (or do all of the presentation in JavaScript for that matter), that shows the parameters a user can select from. These parameter values can then either be sent to a new report or could update the existing report. Parameters can be put into database queries too.

If that was exposed in JavaScript on a web page you could save the parameter values to an array and store them in the browser or server.